# Entity Framework table and not Entity Framework mapping

Tags: entity-framework, mapping

In database present two table

OLD, not EF, modification denied

Object (Id, Name)

UserObjects (Id, UserId, ObjectId)

```cs
public class UserObject
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public Guid UserId { get; set; }

    public int ObjectId { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public string ObjectName { get; set; }
}
```

There are way to fill ObjectName with EF?

Or use SqlCommand and fill UserObject manually?

Comment: You should provide some more informations like: which `ORM` you're using, which language etc...

Comment: C#, MS SQL, Entity Framework 5

Answer (score 0):

I found and use EntityTypeConfiguration

```cs
public class Object
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class UserObject
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public Guid UserId { get; set; }

    public int ObjectId { get; set; }

    public virtual Object Object { get; set; }
}

public class ObjectConfiguration: EntityTypeConfiguration<Object>
{
    public ObjectConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(at => new { at.Id});

        Property(t => t.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);

        ToTable("Objects");
        Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("Id");
        Property(t => t.Name).HasColumnName("Name");
    }
}
```